# Display Android ListView as pages

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview where I'm displaying items as pages with 3 items per page. Depending on user clicking prev or next buttons I am scrolling through the listview using `setSelection`. Here is the code:

```
int size = listView.getCount(); 
int scrollToPosition = 0;
if(direction == PREV)
    scrollToPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() - 3;
else
    scrollToPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() + 3;
if(scrollToPosition < 0) { scrollToPosition = 0; }
else if (scrollToPosition >= size) { scrollToPosition = size - 1; } 
listView.setSelection(scrollToPosition);
```

With this approach, if I have 4 items in the list, the first page shows items 1,2,3 and page 2 shows items 2,3,4. I need to change this such that page 1 shows 1,2,3 and page 2 shows only the 4th item. How do I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make different arrays of element for different page.like arr1 should contain element 1,2,3 and `arr2` should contain 4.And populate `arr1` for page 1 and `arr2` for page 2

Comment: Thanks, based on your idea I actually used part of the original data ArrayList using `subList`. It works.